# How do change a discord command based on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The user can change the command in the settings. This puts it in a variable, but I need that variable to be a bot command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import chalk
import requests
import random

command = "test"

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1.0, 30.0, commands.BucketType.default)
async def command(ctx):
    await bot.say("Test!")
    print ("Test posted")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable as a command name by modifying the `name` attribute in `@bot.command(...)`

```
from discord.ext import commands

c_name = "test"
bot = commands.Bot("@")

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name=c_name)
async def _(ctx):
    await bot.say("Test!")
    print ("Test posted")


bot.run("token")
```

In discord, if you entered:

```
You: @test
Bot: Test!
```